# Adding items to a Microsoft Unified Group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, exchangewebservices

I have some existing code that creates email items into Microsoft 365 folders, using EWS (using SOAP calls directly, not the managed API). Authentication is via OAuth, either individual or via a service account. Now I have a requirement to write messages to a Unified Group. Is there a way that I can easily modify my EWS code for this? There is an email address associated with my test group, however I cannot authenticate with it, since the M365 logon does not recognize the address as valid.

I saw some sample code (from ChatGPT) that suggested putting two Exchange Impersonation/ConnectingSID tags into the SOAP header, one for my normal user and the second for my Group email.  However this resulted in the error "Only one access mode header may be specified".

Would it be better to use Graph for this? Any suggestions or pointers to sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> There is an email address associated with my test group, however I cannot authenticate with it, since the M365 logon does not recognize the address as valid.

Delegate access to the unified group mailbox should work eg if you logon as a service account that then has access to the unified group and use the delegate methods https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/delegate-access-and-ews-in-exchange, or if you use the client credentials flow if you impersonate the service account and then access the unified group mailbox (as a delegate of the service account your impersonating) that should work. What won't work AFIAK is trying to impersonate the Group mailbox itself.

Switching to the conversations endpoint in the Graph https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-conversations?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http is probably a better long term solution as EWS may go away at some point in the future.